# Creating a link in page content?

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, asp.net

I have a html custom master page with html links. I am currently using static url's to link to pages and wondered if there is a way I can use a dynamic path in asp or sharepoint language so that when I export to a production environment, I won't need to change the links manually.

I am looking for something like this, if it's possible:

`http://<site url here>/Pages/Newpage.aspx`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use relative paths, like in most web development, like

```
/_layouts/images/hello.jpg
```

Or use SPUrl tokens inline in the src or href attribute. See more here: http://hristopavlov.wordpress.com/2008/12/08/urlaction-tokens-of-the-customaction-feature/

This link is 2007, but most tokens should still be valid!